# Does manganese dioxide disperse differently in bases than in water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

As part of a project in uni I've been given a task in my chemistry laboratory to synthesise manganese dioxide powders.

I prepared a precipitate of it by reacting manganese chloride with sodium hydroxide and hydrogen peroxide. I got quite a lot of dark brown precipitate and I've been trying to wash it all to be neutral. For this, I'm using a centrifuge. I washed it in water, then ethanol, then water, then ethanol, and then in water until neutral.

The first few washes came out fine - I ran the centrifuge for two minutes each time and the supernatant was very clear. However after the third wash I've had to run the centrifuge for longer and longer to get a clear supernatant. Is this because manganese dioxide disperses more finely in neutral water than in a basic solution?

Comment: Different pH may lead to different particle surface structure and charge, affecting tendency to disperse and to coagulate.